# AWS CLI has my credentials but I don't have a credential file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I can run the AWS CLI `aws configure` command and it lists my credentials. I even have a named profile I use.

However, my system does not have `Users\{profile}\.aws\credentials` file. Where could my credentials be stored?

The following command returns this but ~/.aws/config is empty for all the accounts I have on this machine. I have hidden files shown.

```
$aws configure list
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************BBBB             shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************BBBB             shared-credentials-file
    region                us-east-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? That sounds quite unusual! The location should be `C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\credentials`. Please note that directories starting with a dot _might_ be hidden on your system. Did you try putting putting the full path into a Text Editor to open the file, or perhaps navigating to that directory from the Command Line? Please tell us how you have verified that the `.aws` directory definitely does not exist.

Comment: The credential file should be stored under `%USERPROFILE%\.aws`, whatever that maps to on your system.

Comment: What happens if you type `aws configure list`? It will enumerate values and where the file they're associated with is.

Comment: Be clear that there are two notions of profile here. The Windows environment variable named USERPROFILE e.g. `c:\users\chris` and the AWS configuration profile e.g. `[chris]`, stored in `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials`. There is no such thing as `user\{profile}\.aws\credentials`.

Comment: @wkl updated my answer with that info.

Comment: Are you using WSL on Windows? WSL will have a different 'home' folder to native Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this creating a profile:

1. aws configure --profile {profile-name}
2. set any values
3. The /.aws/ folder have been created and now you can edit their files.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out the location of your AWS credentials should be in **%USERPROFILE%\.aws**

Follow these steps and let's see what you get

1. Open terminal
2. Run: **cd %UserProfile%\.aws**
3. Run: **type credentials**

Another option is that you have added **AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE** environment variable. This changes the default location of the shared credentials file (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html#the-shared-credentials-file). Try these steps:

1. Open terminal
2. Run: **echo %AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE%**
3. Run: **type %AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE%**

Comment: Both steps say they can't find the file specified.

Comment: @ChrisChevalier Run this command in powershell - Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Include *credentials -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue This will find all of the credentials files in the C drive

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar issue and the problem was the company's Comodo Antivirus that redirected my aws-mfa process to some kind of quarantine folder.

1. in C:\ show Hidden items and check if you have VTRoot folder
2. If yes, you might have the same issue: search inside the HarddiskVolume folders the credentials file. My path was `C:\VTRoot\HarddiskVolume3\Users\[my-user-name]\.aws\credentials`
3. An exception for the aws-mfa.exe should be added in Comodo (The sys. admin fixed it in my case)